# Create receipt in pos Odoo-8

Tags: javascript, odoo-8

i'd like to print the template **PosTicket** before to pay it(preview of the ticket), I tried with the module **"pos_restaurant"** but doesn't work, any suggestions?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a js using this code

/* Button Widget   */

```
var PrintBillButtonTicket = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
    template: 'PrintBillButtonTicket',
    print_xml: function(){
        var order = this.pos.get('selectedOrder');
        if(order.get_orderlines().length > 0){
            var receipt = order.export_for_printing();
            receipt.bill = true;
            this.$('.pos-receipt-container').html(QWeb.render('PosTicket',{
            widget:this,
            order: order,
            receipt: order.export_for_printing(),
            orderlines: order.get_orderlines(),
            paymentlines: order.get_paymentlines(),
        }));
        }
    },
    button_click: function(){

       this.print_xml();

    },
});

screens.define_action_button({
    'name': 'print_billticket',
    'widget': PrintBillButtonTicket,

});
```

Add XML File Below

```
<t t-name="PrintBillButtonTicket">
        <span class="control-button order-printbillticket">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
            Bill Print
        </span>
    </t>
```

Comment: Hi, i think that way it's for odoo 10, by the way, this example give me an idea to solve it. Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome...@limfit