# How to add function print reciept for my custom button in POS odoo 11?

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-11

I have created my custom button in POS odoo 11 in template PaymentScreenWidget, i cannot find out the way to give it a function print reciept. How can i do that?

My Button in mymodule/static/src/xml/....xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

        <t t-name="PaymentScreenWidget" t-extend="PaymentScreenWidget">
            <t t-jquery='.payment-buttons' t-operation='append'>
                <div class="control-button">
                    Custom Button
                </div>
        </t>
        </t>
</templates>
```

My js file

```
odoo.define('POS.pos', function (require) {

'use strict';
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
var core = require('web.core');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui');
var qweb = core.qweb;
});
```

My views/...xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="demo_example_ext_js" name="Demo Example Ext Js" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/POS/static/src/js/pos.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759569/7578882

Comment: Check this answer

Comment: Please check my answer below @VishnuVaNnErI, thanks a lot